# How to delete previous added row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on POS system but now I am stuck somewhere I am trying to fix since 3 days but I didn't find a solution

I made a system which when an item is out of stock it will not be added and shows an error, this system worked fine with me. But now what I want to do is, if the Quantity in the datagrid is about to be larger than the item stock in the database it will show error that will tell that cant be added. But I couldn't find a way to do it on my own. My idea to do this is to make, if the quantity > stock, show error and delete last added row.

This is my code

```
//Brcode system =================================================
    //Brcode system =================================================
    //Brcode system =================================================

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        //reading brcode =================================================
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Item_Code = @BarCode", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BarCode", Productstxt.Text));
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in receiptgrid.Rows)
            {                    
                if (Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetInt32(4)) > 1)     //This condition is " If Item stock is avaible add it if not show message box" 
                {
                    prdctname.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + reader.GetString(1));
                    string pname = reader.GetString(1);
                    string price = reader.GetString(2);

                    bool Found = false;

                    if (receiptgrid.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {


                        if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value) == reader.GetString(1) && Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value) == reader.GetString(2))
                        {
                            row.Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToString(1 + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value));
                            Found = true;
                        }

                        if (!Found)
                        {
                            receiptgrid.Rows.Add(pname, price, 1, price, indate.Text);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        receiptgrid.Rows.Add(pname, price, 1, price);
                    }


                    row.Cells[receiptgrid.Columns["Total"].Index].Value = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[receiptgrid.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[receiptgrid.Columns["QTY"].Index].Value);


                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    prdctname.Text = string.Empty;
                    prdctname.Select(0, 0);
                    prdctname.ScrollToCaret();

                    Productstxt.Select(0, 0);
                    Productstxt.ScrollToCaret();
                    Productstxt.Text = string.Empty;

                }
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetInt32(4)) == 1)             // This condition is for "If item stock is out of stock do this"
                {
                    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("This item should be out of stock, Continue anyway?", "POS", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)             //This condition is for "If The user did yes then add it"
                    {
                        prdctname.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + reader.GetString(1));
                        string pname = reader.GetString(1);
                        string price = reader.GetString(2);

                        bool Found = false;

                        if (receiptgrid.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {


                            if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value) == reader.GetString(1) && Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value) == reader.GetString(2))
                            {
                                row.Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToString(1 + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value));
                                Found = true;

                            }
                            if (!Found)
                            {
                                receiptgrid.Rows.Add(pname, price, 1, price, indate.Text);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            receiptgrid.Rows.Add(pname, price, 1, price);
                        }


                        row.Cells[receiptgrid.Columns["Total"].Index].Value = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[receiptgrid.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[receiptgrid.Columns["QTY"].Index].Value);


                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        prdctname.Text = string.Empty;
                        prdctname.Select(0, 0);
                        prdctname.ScrollToCaret();

                        Productstxt.Select(0, 0);
                        Productstxt.ScrollToCaret();
                        Productstxt.Text = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This Item is out of Stock", "POS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                }
                if (Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetInt32(4)) > Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The quantity is larger than the stock", "POS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                }
            }
            reader.Close();



            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: why not compare the stock qty with purchase qty first? if stock qty > purchase qty, then don't add it into the shopping car.

Comment: I did that but this is what will happen, if the item brcode was scanned 3 times while there is only 2 it will allow it...

Comment: so the validator will be: stock qty < purchase qty + receipt qty. If one user scan one item, then query stock qty from Database, query out receipt qty from receiptgrid (using linq .select()), if stock_qty< purchase_qty=1+receipt qty, then do nothing.

Comment: anyway, I think [validate data -> add to shopping car] better than [added->validate->delete]

Comment: You should consider decoupling your POS library code from the UI class.

Comment: Emmmm. I dont really understand you because I am 2 months programmer I just a beginner.